# How to make Robot Custom Library name as a keyword argument?

Tags: robotframework

I want to use given library name as an argument in my keyword as in the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library some_library WITH NAME some_lib_name

*** Keywords ***

FOO
   [Arguments]  ${some_lib_name} ${params}
   ${some_lib_name}.SEND param1
```

But the robot framework gives an error "No keyword with name '${some_lib_name}.SEND' found."
So is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `run keyword` since it will evaluate variables before calling the keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
FOO
   [Arguments]  ${some_lib_name}       ${param1}
   Run keyword  ${some_lib_name}.SEND  ${param1}
```